# How to show some message against a option field in JSP using java script

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I trying to show and message against the option field after selecting the value against the same item. like in this picture I am selecting first member and I want show the "!" mark on some condition against the same box.
[image]

this task are created by variable general task in loop.
I am some how able to print the mark but not able to place it at exact place .
Could anyone help me here how to do that? thanks in advance :)

```
$(function() {
      $(".task-member").on('change', function() {
          var memberCertificationRole = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-certificatedRole');
          console.log(memberCertificationRole);
          if (memberCertificationRole <= 0) {
              var message = getText('member_not_certified_warning');
              document.querySelector('.member-certification').innerHTML = '<span style = "float:Right;color:Red;font-weight:bold" title="' + message + '"> ! </span>';
          } else {
              document.querySelector('.member-certification').innerHTML = '';
          }
      });
  });
```

JSP:

```
<div class="title">
                        <span class="title-label"><s:text name="general_abilities"/>:</span>
                        <div class="title-text" style="width:720px">
                            <c:if test="${not _:isEnableAutoMemberAssignementPerTask()}">
                                <c:forEach items="${generalTasks}" var="task">
                                    <div style="width:240px;float:left">
                                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="service" <c:if test="${_:isStringInStringArr(task.keyType, service)}">checked="checked"</c:if> value="${task.keyType}" />
                                        ${_:getTaskDefinitionName(task)}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${_:isEnableAutoMemberAssignementPerTask()}">
                                <c:forEach items="${generalTasks}" var="task">
                                    <div style="width:360px;float:left" >
                                        <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${task.keyType == RECONSTRUCTION }">
                                                <input style="width:20px;display:none" type="checkbox" name="service" <c:if test="${_:isStringInStringArr(task.keyType, service)}">checked="checked"</c:if> value="${task.keyType}" />
                                            </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="service" class="generalServiceCheckbox" <c:if test="${_:isStringInStringArr(task.keyType, service)}">checked="checked"</c:if> value="${task.keyType}" />
                                                ${_:getTaskDefinitionName(task)}</label>
                                                <c:choose>
                                                <c:when test="${_:is_moCertificationModularEnabled()}">
                                                    <c:set var="assignmentMembers"  value="${taskMembers}"/>

                                                    <c:if test="${task.keyType ==PROJECT_MANAGEMENT_PREPARE }">
                                                        <c:set var="assignmentMembers"  value="${pmMembers}"/>
                                                    </c:if>
                                                    <c:if test="${_:contains(inspectionListArray, task.keyType)}">
                                                        <c:set var="assignmentMembers"  value="${insMembers}"/>
                                                    </c:if>
                                                </c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                    <c:set var="assignmentMembers"  value="${members}"/>
                                                </c:otherwise>
                                                </c:choose>
                                                <select id="task-member" class="task-member" name="autoAssigneeToAbilityMap['${task.keyType}']" style="float:right;width:160px;margin-right:16px;" <c:if test="${not inputOffice.autoMemberSameForAllTasks and not _:isStringInStringArr(task.keyType, service)}">disabled="disabled"</c:if>>
                                                    <option value="0" ></option>
                                                    <c:forEach items="${assignmentMembers}" var="member">
                                                        <option value="${member.id}" data-certificatedRole="${member.certificatedRole}"
                                                        <c:if test="${not member.available}">rel="grey"</c:if>
                                                        <c:if test="${autoAssigneeToAbilityMap[task.keyType] == member.id}"> selected="selected"</c:if>>${_:out(member.name)}</option>
                                                    </c:forEach>
                                                </select>
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>
                                    </div>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:if>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: It looks like `document.querySelector('.member-certification')` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding a span in general task div.
[image]
js:

```
$(function() {
        $(".task-member").on('change', function() {
            var memberCertificationRole = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-certificatedRole');
            var spanId = '#warn_' + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-spanId');
            if (memberCertificationRole <= 0) {
                document.querySelector(spanId).innerHTML = '<span class="member-certificatedRole" style = "float:Right;color:RED;font-weight:bold" title="' + getText('member_not_certified_warning') + '"> ! </span>';
            } else {
                document.querySelector(spanId).innerHTML = '';
            }
        });
    });
```

JSP:

```
<div class="title">
                    <span class="title-label"><s:text name="general_abilities"/>:</span>
                    <div class="title-text" style="width:720px">
                        <c:if test="${not in4:isEnableAutoMemberAssignementPerTask()}">
                            <c:forEach items="${generalTasks}" var="task">
                                <div style="width:240px;float:left">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="service" <c:if test="${in4:isStringInStringArr(task.keyType, service)}">checked="checked"</c:if> value="${task.keyType}" />
                                    ${in4:getTaskDefinitionName(task)}</label>
                                </div>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${in4:isEnableAutoMemberAssignementPerTask()}">
                            <c:forEach items="${generalTasks}" var="task">
                                <div style="width:360px;float:left" >
                                    <c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${task.keyType == RECONSTRUCTION }">
                                            <input style="width:20px;display:none" type="checkbox" name="service" <c:if test="${in4:isStringInStringArr(task.keyType, service)}">checked="checked"</c:if> value="${task.keyType}" />
                                        </c:when>
                                        <c:otherwise>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="service" class="generalServiceCheckbox" <c:if test="${in4:isStringInStringArr(task.keyType, service)}">checked="checked"</c:if> value="${task.keyType}" />
                                            ${in4:getTaskDefinitionName(task)}</label>
                                            <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${in4:isIn4moCertificationModularEnabled()}">
                                                <c:set var="assignmentMembers"  value="${taskMembers}"/>

                                                <c:if test="${task.keyType ==PROJECT_MANAGEMENT_PREPARE }">
                                                    <c:set var="assignmentMembers"  value="${pmMembers}"/>
                                                </c:if>
                                                <c:if test="${in4:contains(inspectionListArray, task.keyType)}">
                                                    <c:set var="assignmentMembers"  value="${insMembers}"/>
                                                </c:if>
                                            </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <c:set var="assignmentMembers"  value="${members}"/>
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                            </c:choose>
                                            <select id="selectAssignmentMember" class="task-member" name="autoAssigneeToAbilityMap['${task.keyType}']" style="float:right;width:160px;margin-right:16px;" <c:if test="${not inputOffice.autoMemberSameForAllTasks and not in4:isStringInStringArr(task.keyType, service)}">disabled="disabled"</c:if>>
                                                <option value="0" ></option>
                                                <c:forEach items="${assignmentMembers}" var="member">
                                                    <option value="${member.id}" data-certificatedRole="${member.certificatedRole}" data-spanId="${task.keyType}"
                                                    <c:if test="${not member.available}">rel="grey"</c:if>
                                                    <c:if test="${autoAssigneeToAbilityMap[task.keyType] == member.id}"> selected="selected"</c:if>>${in4:out(member.name)}</option>
                                                </c:forEach>
                                            </select>
                                            **<span id="warn_${task.keyType}" style = "float:right;color:Red;font-weight:bold;margin-right:16px;"></span>**
                                        </c:otherwise>
                                    </c:choose>
                                </div>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:if>
                    </div>
                </div>
```